# Non-vector icons in Nautilus

Tags: unity, nautilus, icons, vector

I'm happy Acer AOD257 (2GB, Atom) netbook owner with Ubuntu 12.10.

I once saw that all Nautilus/Unity/Ubuntu icons are in raster and vector formats. BUT! I see vector only.

My netbook is weak, does anybody have any solutions?

QUESTION:
**How to enable bitmap icons by default?**

Comment: *BUT! I see vector only* - Can you explain this better?. *How to enable bitmap icons by default?* - All software make use of either Vector and Bitmap image files or both if they're present in the current icon theme  in use.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do that, and for good reason.  For the most part rendering a simple SVG (like an icon) takes roughly as much CPU time as decompressing a PNG.  You're unlikely to see any speedup by switching to only bitmap icons.